# node in docker in aws instance is running out of memory, why?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, memory

My NodeJS application is running inside a docker container on an ec2 instance.
It is running out of memory way before the server itself is running out of memory. The container is only able to use around 25% of the memory. But why?

The following mechanisms seem not to be the cause:

- `ulimit` returns `unlimited`.
- `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/memory.limit_in_bytes` returns `9223372036854771712`

I am running docker without any limiting flags

Comment: Host ulimit and container limit are different also docker use cgroup slice to control the limits. Kindly add appropriate details.

Comment: i added the cgroup information. anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Though you haven't provided docker container limits like how you are running container along with parameters, you can refer to this page https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/ specifically memory related parameters listed here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory

Comment: haven't used any of those flags, by default everything should be unlimited, right?

Comment: nope, container mean cgroups which si coming with limit big no no unlimited stuff, as container meant for different purpose.